# Firebase Database.unitypackage is showing errors when imported into Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I imported the `Firebase` Database unity package into Unity and it is constantly showing me many errors.

```
Unable to find dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.4 in paths ($SDK\extras\android\m2repository, $SDK\extras\google\m2repository).

com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.4 was referenced by:
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace() in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Environment.cs:line 227
   at Google.JarResolver.Dependency..ctor(System.String group, System.String artifact, System.String version, System.String[] packageIds, System.String[] repositories)
   at Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport.DependOn(System.String group, System.String artifact, System.String version, System.String[] packageIds, System.String[] repositories)
   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Object , System.Object[] , System.Exception ByRef )
   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke(System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:line 222
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:line 115
   at Google.VersionHandler.InvokeMethod(System.Type type, System.Object objectInstance, System.String methodName, System.Object[] args, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 namedArgs)
   at Google.VersionHandler.InvokeInstanceMethod(System.Object objectInstance, System.String methodName, System.Object[] args, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 namedArgs)
   at FirebaseAppDeps.SetupDeps() in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\WHOT_2D\Assets\Firebase\Editor\AppDeps.cs:line 52
   at FirebaseAppDeps..cctor() in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\WHOT_2D\Assets\Firebase\Editor\AppDeps.cs:line 23
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(IntPtr )
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(RuntimeTypeHandle type) in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/RuntimeHelpers.cs:line 101
   at UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies.ProcessEditorInitializeOnLoad(System.Type type) in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\EditorAssemblies.cs:line 136
   at UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies.ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes() in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\EditorAssemblies.cs:line 162


UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:<PlayServicesResolver>m__0(String, LogLevel)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:Log(String, LogLevel, Boolean)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:FindCandidate(Dependency, List`1)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:LoadDependencies(Dictionary`2, List`1, Boolean, Boolean)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:LoadDependencies(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:FindMissingDependencyPaths(String, Dictionary`2&, ExplodeAar)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolution(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation, Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Resolve(Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:MenuResolve()

Unable to find dependency com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.4 in paths ($SDK\extras\android\m2repository, $SDK\extras\google\m2repository).
Unable to find dependency com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.4 in paths ($SDK\extras\android\m2repository, $SDK\extras\google\m2repository).
No compatible versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.4 found given the set of required dependencies.
No compatible versions of com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.4 found given the set of required dependencies.
```

I tried Compiling the quick test sample database game like that for android, but i get "One or more Firebase dependencies are not present. Current dependency status: UnavailableOther".
So i tried using that Asserts > Play services Resolver > Android Resolver > Resolve Client Jars. It will print back this error lists instead. Please help me out.

Comment: Open your Android SDK Manager and download Google Play Services. It's one of the Firebase dependency.

Comment: I have already downloaded Google play services and Google play repository. Still the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase plugin, like many other plugins, uses the [Play services resolver](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) to resolve required dependencies.

From the error message, looks like the resolver fails to find what it's looking for:

```
Unable to find dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.4 in paths ($SDK\extras\android\m2repository, $SDK\extras\google\m2repository).
```

Note that the path starts with $SDK, and not not an actual real folder.

You should make sure your Android SDK path is properly set in Unity under Preferences -> External Tools.

Also, make sure that you have the latest versions of Google play services (from SDK manager, make sure the stuff under "Extras" is up to date).